# Put off loading my theme banners to speed up Drupal

Tags: media

I'm currently using the Marinelli theme for a project.  It loads ALL the top banner pictures before showing the page.  Very slow.  Results in a big download size for the home page.  Is there a way to get Drupal or the theme to put off loading all but the first banner pics when it displays the page.  See my screen capture of pingdom.com

Dave

[image: Screen capture of pingdom.com]

Comment: If you can tell us how you'd do this in a non-Drupal site, we can help you implement it in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a technique called "lazy-loading" to implement on your pages. Lazy loading means that the images are only loaded upon viewing them.

You can use [the Lazyloader module](https://drupal.org/project/lazyloader) as a start to implement it, however how it will exactly work for your site is completely dependent on your Drupal theme and module(s) configuration. One useful example (and starting point) is [this blogpost](http://redheadevelopment.com/blog/how-lazy-load-bxslider-drupal-7), which explains how to implement the layloader module in combination with a slideshow.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer unless someone else has other solutions...